# Adding new keys to dictionary in javascript (Its just resetting it) discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, discord.js, reset

Ok, so i have a command called create that i want to add a key and value to a dictionary called `plans`

So the command goes like this: `!create plan.(plan name) (plan)`

Here is my code:

```
if (args[1].startsWith('plan.')) { //This checks if the user wants to create a plan
    name = args[1].replace('plan.', '') //This variable is the same as args[1] but plan. is cut off
    plans[name] = args[2] //This is the code i am having touble with but i want it to add a new key and value to plans
    message.channel.send('Added plan for **' + name + '**') //Message from the bot saying that the plan was added
    console.log(args) //All the print statements that i used to find out the problem
    console.log(plans)
    console.log(name)
}
```

ok so `plans[name] = args[2]`is what i am having trouble with beacuse what happens is when i write (to the bot)

`!create plan.Mod PlanForMod` This is the outpur from the console.log prints:

`[ 'create', 'plan.Mod', 'PlanForMod' ]
{ Mod: 'PlanForMod' }
Mod`

The first one is the `args` variable, second one is the `plans` Dictionary and the third print is the `name` var

This is perfect right? But if i want to add another plan this is my output (i typed `!create plan.Admin Adminplan`)

`[ 'create', 'plan.Admin', 'Adminplan' ]
{ Admin: 'Adminplan' }
Admin`

As you can see, instead of adding another key it just replaces the whole dict with the new key and value

I have another command that will print the plan the user wants

Command: `!plan (plan name)`

Code:

```
let myValue = plans[args[2]]
            message.channel.send(myValue)
            console.log(plans)
```

If i type what i showed you on top here and then type: `!plan Mod` It says that i cant send an empty message, and even if i type: `!create plan.Mod Mod` and then `!plan Mod` It still sais the same thing beacuse when i print out the dict with the `console.log()` command i get this:

`{} 
(node:8456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Bruker\Desktop\BCN\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:8456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:8456) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Notice the empty brackets? It strate up just planked it out!

How can i fix this?

In the sum:
I want the command to add another key but it replaces the whole dict with the new key. And if i try to print it after the whole dict is blank

Comment: instead of using single code line blocks, use mutli, just wrap your code around 3 back ticks start and end (`)

Comment: Sorry, kinda new to this website, ill note that for my next question!

Comment: You can fix it on this question aswell. There's an edit option

Comment: Yeah, i did but do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: Maybe I would if I could read the post, you are still using single line backs for multi line code. Like when you show the output or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is probably with scope

I'm assuming you have some code similar to this

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
  const plans = {};
});
```

or

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
  //...code
  if(args[0] === "plan") {
    const plans = {};
  }
});
```

With either code you are making a new object each time, instead do:

```js
const plans = {};
client.on("message", msg => {
   //code
});
```

This is global scope now but that's a different issue

The problem with the second code is that you are using index 2 instead of 1.

since the args from `!plan Mod` would be `["!plan", "Mod"]` or something similar

another issue would have been the scoping, since it's an empty object I'm assuming your code was similar to the first code block I sent. Should resolve with the fix.